# Почему не срабатывает height: 100% для элемента, когда у его родителя есть свободное место?

Tags: html, css, валидация, textarea, height

Свойство `height` берется от значения родителя, так сказано в документации. У меня в таблице для второй строки, получается указать значение `height` для ячеек (`td`), но вот для `textarea`, внутри них, это не удается.

Вот фрагмент стилей для `textarea`:

```
textarea {
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 8px;
 margin-right: 8px;
 height: 100%;
 width: calc(100% - 32px);
}
```

А вот код всей страницы:

```css
html, body {
 height: calc(100% - 8px);
 width: calc(100% - 8px);
}

table {
 height: calc(100% - 48px);
 width: calc(100% - 8px);
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:not(:nth-child(2)) {
 height: 22px;
}

tr:nth-child(2) {
 height: calc(100% - 22px);
}

tr:nth-child(3) {
 text-align: center;
}

td {
 width: 50%;
 vertical-align: top;
}

th, td {
 border: 1px solid #666666;
}

textarea {
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 8px;
 margin-right: 8px;
 height: 100%;
 width: calc(100% - 32px);
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:not(:first-of-type) textarea {
 margin-left: 16px;
}

button {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 8px;
 width: calc(100% - 22px);
}

td:not(:first-of-type) button {
 margin-left: 8px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 width: calc(100% - 22px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Two columns</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Left column</th>
<th>Right column</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea id="left_text"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea id="right_text"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button>Left button</button></td>
<td><button>Right button</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

В итоге результат:
[image: результат]

Как установить `height: 100%` для `textarea`, чтобы он занимал всю высоту ячейки?

Comment: Все работает, что вы имеете ввиду?textarea занимает всю высоту блока

Comment: @ПоляковРоман добавил же картинку, там явно видно, что `textarea` примерно 60% занимает, а не все пространство...

Comment: Когда я запускаю код здесь или в песочнице у меня все на 100%

Comment: @ПоляковРоман, можно картинку?

Comment: https://ibb.co/1bMRRBX какой браузер у вас?

Comment: @ПоляковРоман фон у `textarea` красный?

Comment: да, для наглядности

Comment: Попробуйте убрать ресайз: resize:none;

Comment: `Resize` у какого элемента?

Comment: у textarea в CSS

Comment: Эх, когда же эти `CSS` будут для всех одинаково работать: у **Chrome** нормально, а у всех **FF** результат, как на картинке. Причина: `tr` тоже хочет `height: 100%`, но почему тогда `td style="height: 100%"` без `height: 100%` для `tr` достаточно для 100% высоты у ячейки, не понятно...

Answer (score 0):

Вместо эпиграфа: *Возможно, я не понимаю принципы CSS, и мой вопрос от неграмотности, но все же, для меня это странное поведение...*

Ответ на вопрос - нужно добавить следующий стиль:

```css
tr:nth-child(2) {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Исходный код, который я указал в вопросе правильно отображается в **Chrome**, а вот в любом **FF** результат как на картинке из вопроса.

Причина, `table > tr > td > textarea`, так вот `tr` тоже нужно установить `height: 100%`, **только вот почему `td` со свойством `height: 100%`, но без этого же свойства у `tr` имеет 100% высоту?!** Для меня это загадка...

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, не надо добавлять ответ, если это не является ответом на ваш вопрос

Comment: @ПоляковРоман, не знаю, я вначале вообще хотел удалить вопрос, но потом посчитал что это будет полезным может кому-то.

Comment: *если это не является ответом на ваш вопрос* - вообще-то является. Установление `height: 100%` для `tr` как раз дает нужный эффект. НО, почему оно в Chrome и без того работает, когда в FF, я проверил под разными системами, и разными версиями браузера, так там результат как на картинке. Хотя, `td` при указании 100% высоты отлично работает и без указания того же у `tr`. Вот этого я не пойму. Магия браузера?

Comment: @ПоляковРоман добавил CSS фрагмент, надеюсь, теперь лучше. Но, может все же кто-то объяснит поведение `td`, который вместо `textarea` нормально работает с `height: 100%`.